# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "DATEADD"; SQL statement

Tags: sql, spring, h2, junit4, spring-jdbc

I'm using h2 to inject the db during run time and testing, everything was working fine until I started trying to make the date field current, not hard-coded. 
I thought it was related to the jdbc version I've and updated spring jdbc library to be the latest, but that didn't solve the problem.

This is the code I'm using to inject the data both on run-time and testing :

**This code runs during run-time, and it works perfectly before I tried to make the date current.**

```
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data.sql"));
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(resourceDatabasePopulator, dataSource); // This is what the DataSourceInitializer does.
```

**For testing purpose, I'm using this code, as I mentioned, it was working perfectly before I tried to make the date current.**

```
        DataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:data.sql")
                .build();
```

**data.sql file**

```
INSERT INTO  TABLE_X (
  dayxx,
  xxx
) VALUES
(CONVERT(char(50), DATEADD('DAY', -1,CURRENT_DATE()),126),'xxx')
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "DATEADD"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TABLE_X ( dayxx, xxx ) VALUES (CONVERT(char(50), DATEADD('DAY', -1,CURRENT_DATE()),126),'XXX') [50004-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:5971)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunctionParameters(Parser.java:3793)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunction(Parser.java:3772)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:4305)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:3343)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:3330)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:3305)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:3108)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:3059)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseValuesForCommand(Parser.java:1877)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsertGivenTable(Parser.java:1817)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1749)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:212)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Isn't [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#convert) the syntax of convert function (value, data type)?

Comment: That's not the problem Matteo

Comment: You are using SQL server's syntax for `CONVERT`. As Matteo has commented, H2's `CONVERT` syntax is different. That explains the error. H2 expects second argument of `CONVERT` to be a data type. `DATEADD` is not a data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the [docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#convert), Convert function looks like this:

> CONVERT ( value , dataType )
>
> Converts a value to another data type.
>
> Example:
>
> CONVERT(NAME, INT)

Since you're passing

> CONVERT(char(50), DATEADD('DAY', -1,CURRENT_DATE()),126)

The error states that DATEADD isn't a valid data type, since it's the value, not the type, so try using the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks Matteo, but how I'm going to convert the date into `YYYY-MM-dd` format without passing `126` value ?

Comment: Could you try with [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#to_char)?

Comment: It works perfectly when I added `TO_CHAR` , thanks for your help, `CONVERT(TO_CHAR(DATEADD('DAY', -1, CURRENT_DATE),'YYYY-MM-dd'),char(50))`